# Usage of (x, 1) (1) in natural deduction

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, natural-deduction

When neither one of premises and conclusion includes a number like "1", like the following, I could at least proceed to some extent (although I don't know how to connect Q(y) of the first premise and Q(x, y) of the second premise...)

```
Premises: 
∀x∀y(P(x,y) ↔ Q(y)) 
∀x∀y(Q(x,y) ↔ R(x,y)) 

Conclusion: 
∀x∀y(P(x,y) ↔ R(x,y)) 

1    ∀x∀y (P(x, y) ↔ Q(y))                   Premiss
2    ∀x∀y (Q(x, y) ↔ R(y))                   Premiss
3    ∀y (P(x, y) ↔ Q(y))                     1 (∀E)
4    (P(x, y) ↔ Q(y))                        3 (∀E)
5    ∀y (Q(x, y) ↔ R(y))                     2 (∀E)
6    (Q(x, y) ↔ R(y))                        5 (∀E)
7    (P(x, y) → Q(y))                        4 (↔E)
..... don't know how to keep going...
```

, but when formulas involve some concrete numbers like "1" shown below, I don't even know where to start from. What's the purpose of using a concrete number instead of general expression like x or y? And how do I work on this problem?

```
Premises: 
∀x∀y(P(x,y)→Q(x,y)) 
∀x(Q(x,1) V R(1))

Conclusion: 
∀xƎy(Q(x,y) V R(y))
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first derivation I assume there is a typo in the first or second premise because the predicate $Q$ is used in the first premise with only one variable, but it has two variables in the second premise.  Assuming the predicate $Q$ has two variables, this would be a proof:

[image]

For the second derivation, view $1$ as a name for a particular value of the variable *y*. For the proof checker that I am using I have to use letters and so I used $a$ as the name instead of $1$.  Here is a proof.

[image]

Notice for this result I only used the second premise.

The proof checker and a text explaining the rules are in the links below.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/

Comment: Thank you for you detailed explanation. But where do the "a" and "b" in your proof come from?

Comment: @ShinichiTakagi Rather than using the name "1", I used the name "a" because the proof checker I use does not allow numbers. The "b" came from universal elimination. I assigned a name, "b", to the variable "x" in line 2. Then in line 3 I could remove the "for all x" symbol.

Comment: Ah, okay. So "a" was a substitute for "1". If you were to write your answer with concrete numbers instead of "a"  and "b", what number would you use for "b"? Would it be "1", or "2"?

Comment: @ShinichiTakagi If the proof checker that I used allowed me to use numbers as names, I would leave 1 as it is because that was what premise 2 used. The universal elimination allows me to use *any* name. I could reuse 1 if I found that convenient. See section 32.1 in the *forallx* text linked in the answer. In this case, however, I would use a different number, say 2 or 3, for clarity since I want to quantify over two variables, x and y.

Answer (score 0):

We can use *terms* of the language, i.e. *variables*, *constant* and "complex" terms built up from "simpler" terms using *function* symbols.

Thus, we can use $1$ if it is part of the language.

In the example above, $1$ is used as a *constant* and it has no special meaning.

Thus, the subformula $R(1)$ simply means that the "object" referred to by $1$ has "property" $R$.

From premise : $∀x(Q(x,1) \lor R(1))$ we derive (using [$(\forall \text E)$](https://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H7)) :

> $Q(a,1) \lor R(1)$

and then we have to use [$(\exists \text I)$](https://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H7) to get :

> $Ǝy(Q(a,y) \lor R(y))$.